# REST api endpoint naming for data formats

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Just wondering on everyone's opinions in regards to naming REST api endpoints when different data formats are in play.

***API example***

- /api/applications - gets a list of all applications
- /api/applications/{applicationId} - gets specific application details
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics - gets all topics for a specific application

***The problem***

Couple of consuming applications may want data delivered in different formats - e.g. list, tree and potentially different verbocity/detail level. What is the best way to represent that in a RESTful API?

***Possible solutions***

**Different endpoint names**. Don't like this as it feels dirty, mixing endpoints and data types:

- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/detailedTopics
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topicHierarchy

**Sub-paths**. Don't like this as it seems to break the RESTful naming conventions. I would expect /topics/{topicId}:

- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics/details
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics/list
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics/hierarchy

**Query string**. This seems like the best solution, but I am still not 100% satisfied with it:

- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics?detail=overview
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics?format=list
- /api/applications/{applicationId}/topics?format=tree

Would be keen to hear some of your thoughts! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the different 'formats' have fundamentally different data, I would personally have different endpoints.

If the 'formats' represent the same data, but it's just organized differently, the standard way to solve this is via the accept header.

For example, if you have a `/topics` endpoint, which supports a `csv` format and two types of json formats, I would use:

```
Accept: text/csv
Accept: application/vnd.ross.list+json
Accept: application/vnd.ross.hierarchy+json
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this is personal preference and what works for you. You didn't necessarily ask about this but, personally, I prefer singular endpoints as you are more likely to have an endpoint dealing with a single entity than list of them.

- GET: /api/applications - list of applications
- GET: /api/applications/{id} - get single application
- POST: /api/applications - create single application
- PUT: /api/applications - edit single application
- PATCH: /api/applications - edit single application
- DELETE: /api/applications - delete a single application

As far as something like topics, I would move it to its own endpoint

- GET: /api/topics?application={applicationId} - list of topics for a specific application

This keeps your endpoints small and leaves you open to add other parameters if you want.

I'm not sure what the whole detail and format parameters are about but if the format is referring to the content type, you could do it either in as a query parameter, like as a file extension, or pass it in the request header.

- /api/appications/{id}.json
- /api/appications/{id}?format=json
- /api/appications/{id} with `Accept: application/json` in the request header.